# Remove the GIT branch pushed by mistake

Tags: git, branch

```
pcA$ git branch -a
* dev
  dev_1
  dev_2
  remotes/svr/dev
pcA$ git push  # only dev --> remotes/svr/dev is desired.
```

However,

```
pcB$ git branch -a
* dev
  remotes/svr/dev
pcB$ git pull
pcB$ git branch -a
* dev
  dev_1
  remotes/svr/dev
```

Please kindly indicate:

1. how to remove dev_1 in svr and and pcB ?
2. how to avoid dev_1 and dev_2 get pushed ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete a Git branch both locally and remotely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete a remote branch using (in svr)

```
git push origin --delete <branchName>
```

To delete a branch in your local (pcB in your case):

```
git branch -D <branchName>
```

Also to push only a single branch to a branch on the remote repository, you can use

```
git push origin <branchName>
```

Also if you face any problem doing this, you can try forcing it using the flag --force, for example:

```
git push origin --delete --force <branchName>
```

Comment: `pcB $ git fetch --prune svr` is recommended for pcB for a more updated view.